# Loop through array of id's and return documents which match with Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I currently have an array which looks as follows (all id's are the same for testing purposes):
[image]

What I need to do is loop through this array and return the user associated with these Id's but cant seem to get it working.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/findUsers",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
        array:array
     },
     success: function (data) {

     }
   })
```

post request:

```
app.post('/findUsers', function(req, res){
    var array = req.body;
    console.log(array);
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      User.find({'_id': array[i]}).exec(function(err, docs){
                 console.log(docs);
            });
         }
        });
```

I can log the array server side but nothing is returned to me?

Logging array in console:
[image]

Comment: Your array property it's a string, so i think you don't need the stringify step

Comment: @catacs if I remove the stringify step I still get no return, is there anything else that could be wrong would you know?

Comment: Can you add to the post the content of req.body? Do you use the body-parser middleware for express?

Comment: @catacs I have updated the question to show what is returned in the console! also I have body-parser declared for the project

Comment: Try `User.findById(array[i])` and see it it helps.

Comment: @Veeram hello again! :) No joy with User.findByID .. but if I hard-code the array in the post request it works? so I'm guessing its something to do with my var array = req.body line but I'm not sure what it could be

Comment: Have you tried `var array = req.body.array;` ? Not sure if that is the issue. Add mongoose debug and check the query and it will help you.

Comment: Yeah that makes it undefined unfortunately! cant seem to get any useful information from the debug either .. if i console.log(array[0]) its undefined also so its almost as if its not recognising that its an array @Veeram

Comment: Take a look at this example maybe It helps https://www.gitbook.com/book/kevinchisholm/handling-post-requests-with-express-and-node-js/details

Comment: Not sure why the key generated is `array[]` in console logs. I'm not really familiar with front end side of things.